# Check code compatibility for python 3x versions

Tags: python, compatibility

I am making a Python script to plot the evolution of a system we are studying in a Physics course. We only use Python 3.6+. I share my code with my classmates and the last time we did such a task, I ran into an annoying issue. I have Python 3.11.4 on my machine because I like having the most recent features of Python. I accidentally used a 3.10 feature which made my code crash for some of my friends who had 3.7-3.9. Is there a way to check which versions of Python my code will work on without installing these versions myself?

I want to make sure the code is compatible with Python 3.7 at least (because I don't give up `dataclasses`). Is there a library, program, or website which can tell me which versions of Python my code will work on?

Alternatively, I am using Visual Studio Code as an editor, so is there a VSCode extension that checks it (it would be nice for VSCode to highlight a compatibility error if it can). Of course, I prefer an editor-independent solution first.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhUpxWjOhME) might be of help to you.

Comment: If you use [Nix](https://nixos.org/), you can tell it to give you any Python interpreter you like so you can have a different one for each project and switch between them at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a library, program, or website which can tell me which
> versions of Python my code will work on?

There exist [vermin](https://pypi.org/project/vermin/) which

> detect the minimum Python versions needed to run code